# Tag Wiki Edits not Showing

Tags: bug, tag-wiki

I recently made an [edit](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/posts/168/revisions) to the "fantasy-based" tab. The edit shows up in the [history](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/posts/168/revisions) of the tag wiki. But if I visit the tag wiki [page](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tags/fantasy-based/info) it doesn't show anything there. [Robert Cartaino](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/52/robert-cartaino) approved the tag wiki edit, I see that in my suggested edit history. I also receive credit for the "Research Assistant" badge. But I don't see the actual edit being made, why is that? Is there something different with tag-wikis during beta?

Note: The history does not show anyone going in and deleting all the stuff I added. The only edit was me adding data to the tag wiki.

Comment: I believe you need 750 rep to approve tag edits but if RC has already approved yours I'm not sure why yours wouldn't be showing up...

Comment: That's odd. At first I thought **caching** (because it's always caching) but the edit was made 16 hours ago now if my math is right, so it should have showed up by now. Maybe the problem is that the tag still doesn't have any tag wiki *summary*?

Comment: I'll try adding that, though we still need moderators to check these.

Comment: @DonyorM I believe someone is on top of this now, so hopefully we will have an answer soon what the problem might be.

Comment: Yay! Thanks for looking at this.

Comment: We pinged the devs to take a look at this.

Comment: @RobertCartaino thanks!

Comment: @RobertCartaino do you know if this will be taken into account when assessing how much we achieved during the private beta?

Comment: @githubphagocyte Yes, any *hiccups* like that would be considered when looking at the overall progress. No problem.

Comment: My suggested edits have now shown up so it looks like this problem may be fixed now.